# Footer won't extend into overflow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, footer, sticky-footer

I am not real experienced when it comes to CSS. I am working with bootstrap and creating a footer. I have got the footer to stick nicely to the bottom of the page.

However, I cant get it to extend into the overflow. In other words, when there is overflow and I scroll right to see the overflow, the area to the right does not have a footer. I have tried messing with the `overflow` and `width` css properties but have had no luck.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EATnm/1/).

Comment: you may combine `width: 100%;` with `min-width: ...px;` for your footer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In that case, would you set the `min-width` to a pixel length that would be definitely larger than the `width` of any other elements? And in that case what would be the purpose of the `width: 100%`?

Comment: it's for when the width of browser is larger than the width of your container, the footer background color will cover the whole width of the browser

Comment: @hmhcreative That makes sense, thanks. And to set the `min-width`, what if the container `width` changes dynamically as the browser resizes? What would you set the width of the footer as? My idea is that I could add an event handler on the `window.resize` event that sets the `min-width` of the footer to the `width` of the container, but I think there is probably an easier way.

Comment: Actually I came up with a solution without using the `min-width`. See my answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any else has this problem, I have come up with a solution. Using the suggestions from hmhcreative, I ended up setting the `position:fixed;` and the `width: 100%;`. 
Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlars62/EATnm/5/).

Thanks everyone!